# Why does `ioctl(fd, EVIOCGRAB, 1)` cause key spam sometimes?

Tags: c, linux, keyboard, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to write my own "keyboard driver" (without actually writing a kernel module),
by grabbing the keyboard at what I assume is the lowest level of abstraction in userland: `/dev/input/event*`.

The following code does the grabbing, provided you change the first ocurrence of `ioctl(fd, EVIOCGRAB, UNGRAB)`
to `ioctl(fd, EVIOCGRAB, GRAB)`.

```
// gcc main.c -o main

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define EXIT_KEY  KEY_ESC
#define UNGRAB    0
#define GRAB      1

const char* kbd_device = "/dev/input/event4";

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(void){
  int fd = open(kbd_device, O_RDONLY);
  if(fd == -1){
    printf("Cannot open %s. %s.\n", kbd_device, strerror(errno));
    return -1;
  }

  if(ioctl(fd, EVIOCGRAB, UNGRAB))
    printf("Couldn't grab %s. %s.\n", kbd_device, strerror(errno));
  else
    printf("Grabbed %s!\n", kbd_device);

  while(1){
    struct input_event event;
    read(fd, &event, sizeof(event));
    if (event.type == EV_KEY && event.value >= 0 && event.value <= 2){
      printf("%d %3d\n", event.value, event.code);

      if(event.code == EXIT_KEY){
        ioctl(fd, EVIOCGRAB, UNGRAB);
        close(fd);
        return 0;
      }

    }
  }
}
```

## Problem

- If I run `gcc main.c -o main && sudo ./main`, everything works as expected.
- If first compile and *then* I run `sudo ./main`, however, the terminal scrolls down nonstop, as if the RETURN key was held down.

Why does happen?

### Notes

- I'm running Ubuntu 14.04
- On my platform, `/dev/input/event4` happens to be the keyboard

### Motivation

I'm trying to write a keyboard "driver" that works both on X and not on X (eg. a TTY).

I understand X11's keyboard library/extension is XKB. I think the TTY's keyboard library is `linux/divers/tty/vt/keyboard.c` ([source](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/vt/keyboard.c)),
the initial keyboard map it uses is in `linux/drivers/tty/vt/defkeymap.map` ([source](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/vt/defkeymap.map)), and it can be modified by using `loadkeys` (source [here](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/legion/kbd/+/6373de5bfc437f60a925ca894308fbbb8b758dc1/src/loadkeys.c)). Do correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you type

```
gcc main.c -o main && sudo ./main ↵
```

GCC takes some time, so the <kbd>↵</kbd> key has been released by the time `./main` runs.

When you type

```
sudo ./main ↵
```

the terminal sends the shell a newline as soon as you push down <kbd>↵</kbd>, and starts executing `./main`. Then the <kbd>↵</kbd> released event is seen by your program, but not by your terminal, because your program has grabbed the input device. Thus, to the terminal it looks like <kbd>↵</kbd> is stuck down, so it continues to produce newlines.

Comment: 2 solutions that work are: 1) quickly doing an `ioctl` that doesn't grab and then doing one that does grab (ie. `ioctl(input.fd, EVIOCGRAB, UNGRAB); ioctl(input.fd, EVIOCGRAB, GRAB);`), 2) adding 100ms of sleep time at startup.
Something that doesn't work is: writing a "key release" event to `/dev/uinput` (which does work for sending other keystrokes). Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: `uinput` probably doesn't work because key release on one keyboard != key release on a different keyboard. :( Assuming you're running in X: If your X has `logind` integration, you can assign the device to another seat which should take it away from X. Or you could use xinput to disable the input from that device to X before you grab it. Either way, you'll want some way of recovering afterward, though.

Answer (score 4):

This question has been answered already, but it still lacks an elegant solution to the problem.

I had the same issue with a driver I implemented some time ago that also required capturing the keyboard.

I could not find a way to force the the kernel to recognize a key release in the device before capturing it, so the solution consists in not grabbing the device until you detect that all keys have actually been released.  This can be accomplished by monitoring the device with the EVIOCGKEY ioctl AFTER opening it and BEFORE grabbing it.

OBS: Please observe that the apparently dummy `read` function within the `while` loop is necessary in order to avoid a busy wait and so that the loop will iterate after each event from the input device.  Also note that the file descriptor must be configured for blocking I/O (the default).

```
void waitReleaseAll(int fd) {

  struct input_event evt;
  unsigned char key_b[KEY_MAX/8 + 1];
  int i, nothing;

  while ( 1 ) {
    memset(key_b, 0, sizeof(key_b));
    ioctl(fd, EVIOCGKEY(sizeof(key_b)), key_b);
    for ( nothing = 1 , i = 0 ; i < KEY_MAX/8 + 1 ; i++ ) {
      if ( key_b[i] != 0 ) { nothing = 0; break; }
    }
    if ( nothing ) break;
    read(fd, &evt, sizeof(evt));
  }
  printf("All keys are now released\n");

}
```

Answer (score -1):

To fix your problem, you should use `SIGINT` in your code to identify `Ctrl-C` keystroke from the user.

### Implement `SIGNAL` in your code:

```
static volatile sig_atomic_t stop = 0;
    
static void interrupt_handler(int sig)
{
    stop = 1;
} // Outside of the main function.

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    signal(SIGINT, interrupt_handler);
    while (!stop) {
    //your code    
    }
    exit(0);
}
```