# EVIOCGRAB newline from terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, keyboard-events

I am grabbing the keyboard using `ioctl(fd,EVIOCGRAB,(void*)1)`, but the terminal keeps sending the shell newlines from executing the program. The same problem as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41995349/why-does-ioctlfd-eviocgrab-1-cause-key-spam-sometimes).

Is there a way to solve this without calling `sleep()` before `ioctl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to read from the keyboard device once before calling `ioctl(fd,EVIOCGRAB,(void*)1)`.

Please let me know if there is a better way.